# Dynamic Table with HTML, Javascript, and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Based on this [project](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/create-dynamic-form-using-php-jquery-and-mysql.php) , I want to modify this js function with my own table. Focus at this code

```
$("#employee_table tr:last").after("<tr id='row"+$rowno+"'><td><input type='text' name='name[]' placeholder='Enter Name'></td><td><input type='text' name='age[]' placeholder='Enter Age'></td><td><input type='text' name='job[]' placeholder='Enter Job'></td><td><input type='button' value='DELETE' onclick=delete_row('row"+$rowno+"')></td></tr>");
```

When I try to modify that code to this :

```
 $("#employee_table tr:last").after("<tr id='row"+$rowno+"'>
    <td>input type='text' name='name[]' placeholder='Enter Name'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='age[]' placeholder='Enter Age'></td>   <td><input type='text' name='job[]' placeholder='Enter Job'></td>
    <td><input type='button' value='DELETE' onclick=delete_row('row"+$rowno+"')></td></tr>");
```

It's not work. If I can modify and work, then I can try for my own table code.

If I can seperate each of , I can modify my table code :

```
<label><h6>HISTORY OF OWNERSHIP</h6></label>
            <table  class="table table-borderer" border="3" id="add_history"  style="width: 100%; border-color: white" >
           <thead class="text-uppercase" style="background-color: #b3b3ff;border-width: 3px;color:black;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;" >
           <tr>
                      <th style="vertical-align: middle;font-size:12px;font-weight: bold">No</th>
                      <th style="vertical-align: middle;font-size:12px;font-weight: bold">Owner</th>
                      <th style="vertical-align: middle;font-size:12px;font-weight: bold">Remarks</th>
                      <th style="vertical-align: middle;font-size:12px;font-weight: bold">Action</th>
            </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
            <?php
            $no = 0;
            $no++;
            ?>          
            <td style="text-align: center"><input style="width: 150px;max-height: 30px;text-align: center"  class="form-control" type="text" name="no_history[]" value = "<?php echo $no ?>" readonly/></td>
            <td style="text-align: center">
            <select type="text" name="owner2[]" class="form-control" style="text-align: center;font-size: 10px;max-height: 35px">
            <option value="-">-</option> 
            <?php
            $sqlowner = "SELECT * FROM owner ORDER BY owner ASC";
            $hasilowner = mysqli_query($connect2,$sqlowner);
            while ($rowowner = mysqli_fetch_array($hasilowner,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                $owner = $rowowner['owner'];
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $owner?>"><?php echo $owner?></option> 
             <?php
                            }
                            ?>                          
                            </select>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center"><input style="width: 150px;max-height: 30px;text-align: center"  class="form-control" type="text" name="remarks[]" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" style="text-transform:uppercase"/></td>
            <td style="text-align: center">
            <input type="button" onclick="add_row();" value="ADD ROW" class="btn btn-primary">
            </td>
            </tbody>     
            </table>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: It's not error but when I enter each <td>, It's not show dynamic form

Comment: can you also include your HTML

Comment: @NidhinJoseph, Please check my code

Comment: @FranksyeSipangkar Please share your code - or even better, a minimal example that reproduces the error - instead of a link.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is missing syntax's in your code where you are trying to insert. Secondly, you can use [back-ticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) when your string goes more tha

```js
var $rowno = 0;

function add_row() {
  $("#add_history tr:last").after(`
    <tr id='row${$rowno}'>
    <td><input type='text' name='name[]' placeholder='Enter Name'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='age[]' placeholder='Enter Age'></td>   
    <td><input type='text' name='job[]' placeholder='Enter Job'></td>
    <td><input type='button' value='DELETE' onclick=delete_row('row${$rowno}')></td></tr>
 `);
  $rowno++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table table-borderer" border="3" id="add_history" style="width: 100%; border-color: white">
  <thead class="text-uppercase" style="background-color: #b3b3ff;border-width: 3px;color:black;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;">
    <tr>
      <th style="vertical-align: middle;font-size:12px;font-weight: bold">No</th>
      <th style="vertical-align: middle;font-size:12px;font-weight: bold">Owner</th>
      <th style="vertical-align: middle;font-size:12px;font-weight: bold">Remarks</th>
      <th style="vertical-align: middle;font-size:12px;font-weight: bold">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td style="text-align: center"><input style="width: 150px;max-height: 30px;text-align: center" class="form-control" type="text" name="no_history[]" value="" readonly/></td>
    <td style="text-align: center">
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><input style="width: 150px;max-height: 30px;text-align: center" class="form-control" type="text" name="remarks[]" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" style="text-transform:uppercase" /></td>
    <td style="text-align: center">
      <input type="button" onclick="add_row();" value="ADD ROW" class="btn btn-primary">
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Big Thanks for you...I want to test it with my own table code.